# Get event cover (Facebook API)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

For some reason the Facebook event object I receive from the API doesn't give me an event cover photo. I have tried numerous methods, but I haven't achieved success thus far.

Does anybody know what's the dealio here? I mean, the entire "object" doesn't give me a coverphoto. Is there any way of grabbing the url of this picture? Anything else, like, the event name, description, date is retrieved tho.

Comment: The problem was that facebook doesn't automatically link an event with a cover. I had to insert a second request which links the event ID to the unique cover. 

So within the request of your 'event', you can run a second request which requests the cover of the unique event ID. 

In my honest opinion, I think facebook should link this by default.

Comment: (Stackoverflow has blocked my answer, but this is the solution to my problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to request each field explicitly that you are interested in, so

```
/{event_id}?fields=id,name,cover
```

should work if you replace `{event_id}` with a real event id.